# Как освободить память, выделенную под создание второго окна в Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

Я создаю новое окно в программе при нажатии на кнопку следующим образом (оба окна принадлежат классу `QMainWindow`):

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
        ImageViewer* imgV = new ImageViewer;
        imgV->show();
}
```

Как грамотно освободить память, выделенную под хранение объекта класса нового окна?
Если прописать `delete` сразу после вызова `show()`, оба окна закроются. Также мне не доступен метод `exec()`, так как второе окно принадлежит классу (как было сказано выше) `QMainWindow`.

Comment: Если второе окно должно существовать дольше, чем выполняется один метод, тогда нужно объявить указатель `imgV` в классе `MainWindow`, выделить память в конструкторе, а удалить в деструкторе.

Comment: А если я захочу открыть несколько таких окон?

Comment: если надо чтобы окно автоматически удалялось при закрытии, проще всего поставить ему атрибут `setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);` https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum

Comment: да, это работает. можете оформить свой комментарий как ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для автоматического удаления окна при закрытии ему надо установить соответствующий атрибут:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
        ImageViewer* imgV = new ImageViewer;
        imgV->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);   // <- вот этот
        imgV->show();
}
```

Подробнее тут: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum

Для полноты ответа добавлю, если время жизни дочернего объекта должно заканчиваться с окончанием времени жизни родителя, то проще всего оставить работу с памятью фреймворку. Для этого в конструктор дочернего окна надо передать указатель на родителя:

```
ImageViewer* imgV = new ImageViewer(this);
```

В этом случае при удалении текущего окна, окно `imgV` удалится автоматически, как и все его дочерние объекты вниз по иерархии.

Comment: А для первого окна, которое объявляется в функции main, этого делать не надо? Почему?

Comment: Первое окно обычно аллоцировано на стеке и будет удалено автомагически когда закрытие окна приведет к возврату из ф-ции main. Ну или если его почему-то выделили на куче и не удалили, ось подберет оставшуюся память, но в этом случае деструктор окна не будет вызван и если вы рассчитываете на какие-то действия, которые должны выполниться в деструкторе (настройки там сохранить и все такое), то вас ждет неприятный сюрприз

Comment: Наверное, можно и первое окно выделять в куче и устанавливать атрибут, если предполагается, что пользователь может открыть новое окно и закрыть старое?
В этом случае не вижу смысла продолжать держать в памяти объект старого окна.

Comment: Это зависит от того, как у вас в программе работают окна. Чаще всего есть главное окно, при закрытии которого закрывается все приложение. Если это не так, то конечно есть варианты